# Java 8's FXML created with SceneBuilder 2.0 combined with a NetBeans Gluon (plugin) project?

Tags: android, javafx, fxml, netbeans-8, javafxports

I'm able to create and run a JavaFX FXML "hello world" program using NetBeans. I installed the Gluon plugin that will allow JavaFX programs to deploy to the desktop, IOS, and Android using the same code base. I'm trying to combine the two (FXML)... to get a 'hello world" program, in which the GUI portion was created in FXML using SceneBuilder 2.0, and be deployed to the desktop, Android, & IOS via the projects built with a project created by the Gluon plugin.

Here's the code from the main method...

```
package com.troyfirstgluonfxapplication;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author tfrericks
 */
public class TroyFirstGluonFXApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
     }

     /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Here's the code from the controller...

```
package com.troyfirstgluonfxapplication;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

/**
 *
 * @author tfrericks
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

And here is the FXML...

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.troyfirstgluonfxapplication.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The error I receive is...

```
Executing: gradle run

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaMain UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileAndroidJava SKIPPED
:compileRetrolambdaAndroid SKIPPED
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileRetrolambdaTest SKIPPED
:compileRetrolambda UP-TO-DATE
:compileDesktopJava UP-TO-DATE
:processDesktopResources UP-TO-DATE
:desktopClasses UP-TO-DATE
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.ja va:363)
at  com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at  com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
at  com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl .java:157)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/1732398722.run(Unknown  Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3201)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
at  com.troyfirstgluonfxapplication.TroyFirstGluonFXApplication.start(TroyFirstGluonFXApplication.java:23)
at  com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImp l.java:821)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1284648825.run(Unknown  Source)
at  com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:3 23)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$44/1051754451.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1830989796.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291 )
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown  Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application  com.troyfirstgluonfxapplication.TroyFirstGluonFXApplication
:run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished    with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.29 secs



Build failure (see the Notifications window for stacktrace): gradle run
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Troy.

#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that it can't find the FXML file.

Under the Resources [Main] package on the Projects view, you should create the package `com.troyfirstgluonfxapplication` and there place the `FXMLDocument.fxml`file.

If you check the Files view, you should have something like this:

```
src
  |-- main
  |    |-- java
  |    |     |-- com
  |    |     |    |-- troyfirstgluonfxapplication
  |    |     |    |     |-- TroyFirstGluonFXApplication.java
  |    |     |    |     |-- FXMLDocumentController.java
  |    |-- resources
  |    |     |-- com
  |    |     |    |-- troyfirstgluonfxapplication
  |    |     |    |     |-- FXMLDocument.fxml
```

Also note that you can combine the fxml load with the code that the plugin generates for you:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, visualBounds.getWidth(), visualBounds.getHeight());

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: I moved my FXML document to 'resources', and added a "/" inside the quotes of the reference (ie, FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FXMLDocument.fxml")); ) and got it to work. Appreciate the help and the additional information about combining FXML load & plugin code!

Comment: Those that are reviewing this question may be interested in the very recent GLUON post... http://gluonhq.com/comments-app-getting-started-with-gluon-charm/